# Setting value to form field while selecting from a drop down in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am having a dropdown(select) box, which contains a list of applications. Drop down will display the application names. 
This is how it is getting populated.

1. My form (QuestionForm) has a list of `<Application>.`

   2. Application is a class with two variables. [id(application id) & applicationName]
   3. I use  ng-option to populate the  tag of select box. following is the code used.

> ```
> <li><span>Application:</span> <span><select ng-model="**questionForm.applicationId**"
> ng-options="application.applicationName for application in questionForm.applicationList track by application.id"
> ng-init="select = 0" required="required">
>   <option value="">-- select -- </option>
> </select></span>
> ```

on selection of an Application from drop down, I am expecting the **id** value to be stored to **applicationId** field of **questionForm**. But instead it is storing the entire Application object to the applicationId field.

I went through several threads that discuss similar topic. Since I am pretty new to angularjs, I am not able to figure it out from the accepted answers in them.

This is how it is getting populated.
[image]

I want it to be "applicationId:"AID_1""

Comment: What does it have to do with Java?

Comment: I work with Spring mvc & angularjs. I'll remove it if it is misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

> `application.id as application.applicationName for application in
>   questionForm.applicationList...`

like so:

```
<li>
  <span>Application:</span> 
  <span>
    <select ng-model="**questionForm.applicationId**" ng-options="application.id as application.applicationName for application in questionForm.applicationList track by application.id" ng-init="select = 0" required="required">
      <option value="">-- select -- </option>
    </select>
  </span>
</li>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jax. That is really an annoying syntax. It will be great if you can explain it in simple words.

Comment: Basically it is 'show the names in the dropdown but pass the id's' to the controller, maybe?